# Exception Correlation failed with Okta and asp.net.core

Tags: asp.net-core, okta, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application with Okta identity. Everything works well except for when a new user signs up. Okta then sends a verification email to the user with an activation link and when that link is clicked I get the following exception:

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I tried to clone the [asp net core sample app](https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnetcore) provided by Okta, but get the same error. I setup a new OIDC application in Okta for this purpose with the following parameters:

Login redirect URI: https://localhost:44314/authorization-code/callback

Logout redirect URI: https://localhost:44314/signout/callback

Nothing else changed from default settings.